# flatten object made of nested list in terraform

Tags: list, object, kubernetes, terraform, flatten

I have the following variable that I try to parse :

**variable.tf**

```hcl
variable "rbac_roles" {
  type = object(
    {
      view = list(object({
        group_name = string,
        group_id = string,
        namespaces = list(string)
      })),
      edit = list(object({
        group_name = string,
        group_id = string,
        namespaces = list(string)
      })),
      admin = list(object({
        group_name = string,
        group_id = string,
        namespaces = list(string)
      }))            
    }
  )
}
```

**variable.tfvars**

```hcl
rbac_roles = {
  view = [
    {
      group_name = "group1",
      group_id   = "123",
      namespaces = ["default", "namespace1"]
    },
    {
      group_name = "group2",
      group_id   = "456",
      namespaces = ["namespace2"]
    }
  ],
  edit = [
    {
      group_name = "group1",
      group_id   = "123",
      namespaces = ["namespace2"]
    }
  ],
  admin = [
    {
      group_name = "group3",
      group_id   = "789",
      namespaces = ["default, namespace1, namespace2"]
    },

  ]
}
```

I try to create the following resources :

```hcl
resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "view_cluster_role_binding" {
  metadata {
    name = ${group}-${namespace}-viewer-binding
    namespace = ${namespace}
  } 
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = "view"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = ${group}
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}  
resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "edit_cluster_role_binding" {
  metadata {
    name = ${group}-${namespace}-viewer-binding
    namespace = ${namespace}
  } 
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = "edit"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = ${group}
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
} 
resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "admin_cluster_role_binding" {
  metadata {
    name = ${group}-${namespace}-viewer-binding
    namespace = ${namespace}
  } 
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = "admin"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = ${group}
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

So far I have tried to `flatten()` my list and to loop over it with `for` and `foreach` but I haven't been successful yet. From what I understand I need to use a `locals{}` to reach my goal, but I can't get the right syntax. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Why would you need `flatten`? From the information provided in the question, you could do this with a quick and easy `for_each = var.rbac_roles["view"]`. Is there some other nuance or subtlety here?

Comment: Yup, as @MattSchuchard said, you are referencing the variable and its values in a wrong way.

Comment: But how am I supposed to loop over my namespaces afterward ? I might have gotten lost as it's been a few hours I'm stuck >>

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin : I've posted as an answer the code I came up with. I'll be please to read your feedback concerning the used approach :)

Comment: Thanks, but I already gave you the answer how to flatten the list? It didn't work?

Comment: I got my below code to work few minutes before you posted the answer so I want with it. Still your code works fine ;)

Comment: If code works, you can accept the answer. You can accept your own answer if you want. Without acceptance the issues appears unresolved.

Comment: @Will No problem. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First this is wrong `["default, namespace1, namespace2"]`. It should be `["default", "namespace1", "namespace2"]`. Once you fix that, you can flatten your data structure as follows:

```
locals {
   flat_rbac_roles = merge([
         for role, groups in var.rbac_roles:
           merge([
             for group_idx, group in groups:
               {
                 for namespace_idx, namespace in group["namespaces"]:                     
                       "${role}-${group_idx}-${namespace_idx}" => {
                       role_name = role
                       group_name = group["group_name"]
                       group_id = group["group_id"]
                       namespace = namespace
                   }
               }
           ]...)
     ]...)
}
```

which gives:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "admin-0-0" = {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "group_id" = "789"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group3"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "default"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "role_name" = "admin"                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "admin-0-1" = {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "group_id" = "789"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group3"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "namespace1"                                                                                                                                                                                
    "role_name" = "admin"                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "admin-0-2" = {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "group_id" = "789"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group3"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "namespace2"                                                                                                                                                                                
    "role_name" = "admin"                                                                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "edit-0-0" = {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    "group_id" = "123"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group1"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "namespace2"                                                                                                                                                                                
    "role_name" = "edit"                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "view-0-0" = {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    "group_id" = "123"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group1"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "default"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "role_name" = "view"                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  "view-0-1" = {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    "group_id" = "123"                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "group_name" = "group1"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "namespace" = "namespace1"                       
    "role_name" = "view"                             
  }                                                  
  "view-1-0" = {                                     
    "group_id" = "456"                               
    "group_name" = "group2"                          
    "namespace" = "namespace2"                       
    "role_name" = "view"                             
  }                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `flatten()` approach :

```hcl
resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "default_roles_binding" {

  for_each = {
    for binding in flatten([
      for role_name, groups in var.rbac_roles : [
        for group in groups : [
          for ns in group.namespaces : [
            {
              binding_name = lower("${ns}-${group.group_name}-${role_name}")
              role         = role_name
              group_id     = group.group_id
              group_name   = group.group_name
              ns           = ns
            }
          ]
        ]
  ]]) : binding.binding_name => binding }


  metadata {
    namespace = each.value.ns
    name      = each.value.binding_name
    annotations = { "group_name" : each.value.group_name }
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = each.value.role
  }
  subject {
    kind = "Group"
    name = each.value.group_id
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks
  ]  
}
```